# Using Pip, how do I force upgrade non-upgraded packages only?

Tags: python, setuptools, pip

When running Pip with a `requirements.txt` file which has fixed versions, we get the following error (or similar):

```
VersionConflict: (solrpy 0.9.1 
(.../lib/python2.6/site-packages/solrpy-0.9.1-py2.6.egg),
    Requirement.parse('solrpy==0.9.3'))
```

because the version conflicts. Using `pip install -U -r requirements.txt` fixes this, but it also forces us to download all the packages again. One of the nice things about Pip is that it will know what's installed and not re-download/install it.

Is there any way around this? I guess what I want is a "soft upgrade", where it only upgrades the packages if they conflict.

Comment: Yes, -U currently re-downloads all installed packages. It's a bug and should be fixed. In an unrelated note, if you're seeing that VersionConflict error, it indicates you're running a version of pip that is at least half a year old. That's ancient in pip terms; I highly recommend not using OS packages for pip, but getting the most recent version direct from PyPI.

Comment: Thanks Carl, that's helpful. Is it worth adding a +1 to the bug report mentioned below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems there is an outstanding bug for this: http://bitbucket.org/ianb/pip/issue/13/

Answer (score -1):

Upgrade the solrpy package separately:

```
pip install -U --no-deps solrpy
```

I think you can probably omit the `--no-deps` parameter, but you might want to try this first, and the former second, if you have problems:

```
pip install -U solrpy
```

I don't believe there is a way to just update higher versioned packaged already installed from a `requirements.txt` file.